# Form to change one variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, form-for

I have a table with a list of items; one column of the table offers the opportunity to check off an item as "Completed." I'm using f.check_box and f.submit. The form thinks it's saving, but it's not affecting the items in the database at all.

My view code is:

```
<td><div><%= form_for [t] do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :completed, {}, "true" %>
        <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
      <% end %></div></td>
```

My controller code is:

```
def update
    @todo = Todo.find params[:id]
    if @todo.save 
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice] = "Success!"
    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice] = "Please try again."
    end
end
```

When I click a checkbox and click that line's "Save" button, I get redirected back to the list and get the "Success!" message, but nothing's happening in the database.

The only thing I can think of is that when I view source on my list, there are two different methods being called by the checkbox, "post" and "patch". I had to create the PATCH route in my routes.rb because otherwise the checkboxes wouldn't resolve at all:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/todos/53" class="edit_todo" id="edit_todo_53"         method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="gUQ5ByGVYFncKW+6Rd/hYqiRE+DV5B1IS88EG1hZbBo=" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the object is not changed, is because there is no code at all to instruct the object to be changed.

```
def update
  @todo = Todo.find params[:id]
  if @todo.save
```

Here you fetch the object, and then you save it, but you don't modify it.

You can change your action to use `update` instead of `save`, and pass the new values from the form.

```
def update
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  if @todo.update(params[:todo])
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, this will allow the user to potentially change any field in the object. Therefore, you need to filter only the allowable fields.

```
def update
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  if @todo.update_attribute(todo_params)
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end

def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:completed)
end
```

or use a specific single-update

```
def update
  @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
  if @todo.update_attribute(todo_params[:completed])
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end

def todo_params
  params.require(:todo)
end
```

Last but not least, using a custom model method would make your controller more maintainable and testable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed, reasoned explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Within your `update` action you should have:

```
def update
  @todo = Todo.find params[:id]
  if @todo.update todo_params 
    # ...
  end
end

private 

def todo_params
  # ...
end
```

`save` only persists the current state of `@todo`, however it hasn't been changed anywhere.

ps. I assume you're using at least Rails 4.0